# Error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::list<std::pair<int, int> >*' and 'std::pair<int, int>')

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to create a graph where each node is a pair of two `int` values. For this I have created a list `adj` of type pii `(pair<int, int>)`. Now when I try to `push_back` a pii type node in the list it says

`error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::list<std::pair<int, int> >*' and 'std::pair<int, int>')|`

Here's my code. ( I haven't added the edges from `main()` yet). I've included all the necessary headers. I've searched but can't find a similar error.

```
#define pii pair<int, int>
#define lli long long int
using namespace std;

class graph
{
    lli v;
    list<pii> *adj;
    public:
    graph(lli v);
    void addEdge(pii n, pii m);
    void bfs(pii s);
};

graph::graph(lli v)
{
    this->v = v;
    adj = new list<pii >[v];
}

void graph::addEdge(pii n, pii m)
{
    adj[n].push_back(m);        //Error Line
}

void graph::bfs(pii s)
{
    bool visited[v];
    memset(visited, false, sizeof(visited));

    list<pii> q;
    list<pii>::iterator it;
    q.push_back(s);
    while(!q.empty())
    {
        pii temp = q.front();
        q.pop_front();
        for(it = adj[temp].begin() ; it != adj[temp].end() ; it++)
        {
            if(!visited[*it])
            {
                visited[*it] = true;
                q.push_back(*it);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n, m, i, j;
    pii coordinates;
    cin>>n>>m;
    char input[n][m];
    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0 ; j < m ; j++)
        {
            cin>>input[i];
            make_pair(i, j);
        }
    }
    graph(n*m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Um... you know you're indexing with a `std::pair<int,int>` type as the subscript, not an `long long int`, right? Look at the *type* of `n` (`pii`), which you've apparently tried extensively to hide in a macro.

Comment: obfuscating succeded. Just dont use strange macros and you will be able to read your own code :P

Comment: @WhozCraig `n` is pii type which is nothing but `pair<int, int>` only. Not sure what you are trying to say.

Comment: He's trying to say you can't use a `std::pair` to index an array. You need an integer and preferably an unsigned integer. That array leaks memory and helps `graph` violate [the Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), by the way. I recommend [hitting the books to pick up some of the basics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282) before you go too much further. Looks like you've been trying to learn from competition code, and it's not doing you much good.

Comment: This makes sense. I'll try to modify my code. Yes, I've been doing CP for some time (ad-hocs and mathematics mostly). Recently started Graph theory hence the noob mistakes. Appreciate the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

`adj` is of type `std::list<std::pair<int, int>>*`, which is a pointer. Pointers implement the following `operator[]`

```
T & operator[](T *, std::ptrdiff_t);
```

You're trying to call the following:

```
T& operator(T*, std::pair<int, int>);
```

You need to call `operator[]` with a type of `std::ptrdiff_t` which is a signed integer.

```
void graph::addEdge(***int*** n, pii m)
{
    adj[n].push_back(m);        //Error Line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the direct answer to your question is that you are attempting to index a pointer with a `pii` (which you have `#defined` as `pair<int,int>`), and since a `pii` has no automatic conversion to an integer, it cannot be used as an index.

Looking at the broader picture, because of your abbreviated variable and method names, it is hard to see what it is you are trying to do. Is your intent that `adj` be an array of lists? If so, you just need to change the first parameter to addEdge to `int`, so that it can be used as an index into this array. But from a quick look through the method `bfs`, it looks like perhaps `adj` is intended to just be a list, in which case you can remove the asterisk from its declaration and eliminate its assignment in the graph constructor, and eliminate the indexing altogether. Or if what you are trying to do is to map one `pii` to another `pii`, you would need to use something like `std::map` instead of `std::list`.

Comment: I am solving this problem [link](http://www.spoj.com/problems/HERDING/) .I thought of making a graph from the matrix coordinates and then apply BFS and count the no. of connected components. My intent is to use `adj` as an array of lists where each list stores the adjacent nodes. So I was trying to insert adjacent node `m` to the current node `n` in the problem. Hence I declared `n` as pii (because its a node). But now I know I can't iterate with a pair value so I need to know how do I store pair values in list and iterate it?

Comment: Interesting problem. I'm not quite sure how BFS applies here (I understand BFS when related to a tree, but not a general graph like this one would be), nor exactly what you mean by "making a graph from the matrix coordinates". And there is so much logic related to the problem that is missing from the code you provided that I'm finding it hard to guide you in a particular direction. Like what is the purpose of the `bfs` method?